# yadcf does not seem to work at all

Tags: javascript, datatables, yadcf

I am using DataTables v 1.10.16, and yadcf v 0.9.1, with a range_date filter. The column header properly displays the input boxes for the dates, however I am getting the following two issues, making it unusable:

1) The date_format param is not respected - I gave it 'mm-dd-yyyy' and it still uses '/' characters. I would actually prefer 'yyyy-mm-dd' but the docs seem to say that this is not supported.

2) The table never gets redrawn, filtering out the rows.

I am not getting any console errors.

Here is my initialization code:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  var dt = $('#sessions-table').DataTable({
    'order': [[1, 'desc']]
  }).on('draw.dt', function() {
    $('.delete-link').off('ajax:success');
    $('.edit-button').off('click');
    initPage();
  }); 

  yadcf.init(dt, [
    { column_number: 1, filter_type: 'range_date', date_format: 'mm-dd-yyyy' }
  ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I was using bootstrap-datepicker and this was interfering with the datepicker widget the plugin is trying to use. Removing it and using jquery-ui datepicker solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the docs about date filtering - [datepicker_type](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L242)

> - datepicker_type
>                 Required:           false
>                 Type:               String
>                 **Default value:      'jquery-ui'** |
>                 **Possible values:    'jquery-ui' / 'bootstrap-datetimepicker'**
>                 Description:        You can choose datapicker library from defined in special notes
>                 Special notes:      Currently supported only *jQueryUI datepicker* (datepicker) and Bootstrap datepicker (*eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker*)
>                                     Bootstrap datepicker depends moment library. This plugin depends moment too.